# Evaluate the following indefinite integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, indefinite-integrals

Evaluate the integral : $$\int\frac{1-x}{(1+x)\sqrt{x+x^2+x^3}}\,dx$$

I tried through putting $x=\tan \theta$ as well as $x=\tan^2\theta$ .but I am unable to remove the square root. I also tride by putting $x+x^2+x^3=z^2$. But I could not proceed anyway...Please help...

**Update :**

putting $x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$ , I get , $$\sqrt{x+x^2+x^3}=\sqrt{\frac{2-3t+t^2-t^3}{(1+t)^3}}$$

How you got $\sqrt{x+x^2+x^3}=\sqrt{(t^3+3)(1-t^2)}/(t+1)^2$ ?

Comment: Wolfram Alpha provides the answer in terms of elliptic integrals. It may be best to use the result provided there if just using the value.

Comment: By dividing the integration interval into $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty)$, then letting $t=\dfrac1x$ on the latter, we have $$\int_0^\infty\frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x+x^2+x^3}}~dx~=~0.$$ At the same time, it is worth noticing that the integral on each of the two intervals equals $\pm\dfrac\pi3$.

Comment: @Lucian, how would you go about proving the $\pi/3$ case?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: $~t=\dfrac{1-x}{1+x}~,~$ followed by $t=\sin u$ and $y=\cos u$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** $t \mapsto (1-x)/(1+x)$

> $$\begin{equation}\displaystyle\int\frac{x-1}{(x+1)\sqrt{x+x^2+x^3}}\,\mathrm{d}x = 2\arccos\left(\frac{\sqrt{x}} {x+1}\right) + \mathcal{C}\end{equation}$$

**Hint 2:** One can show that $t = (1-x)/(1+x)$ is it's own inverse. In other words $x = (1-t)/(1+t)$. Hence the derivative becomes. $\mathrm{d}x = -2t \,\mathrm{d}t/(t+1)^2$.
Similarly we have $\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x} = \sqrt{(t^3+3)(1-t^2)}/(t+1)^2$ so we get a nice cancelation. Explicitly we have
$$
\begin{align*}
\sqrt{x^3+x^2+x}
& = \sqrt{ \left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^3 + \left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right)^2 + \left(\frac{1-t}{1+t}\right) } \\
& = \sqrt{ \frac{-t^3+t^2-3t+3}{(1+t)^3}} = \sqrt{ \frac{1+t}{1+t}\frac{(1-t)(t^2+3)}{(1+t)^3}} = \frac{\sqrt{(1-t^2)(t^3+3)}}{(t+1)^2}
\end{align*}
$$

**Hint 3:** Use the substitution $\cos u \mapsto t$, what happens?

Comment: This agrees with Lucian's evaluation since $2(\pi/2-\pi/3) = \pi/3$ with opposite signs for the two intervals. It might be nice for the OP to show some intermediate steps.

Comment: It might be nice if the OP shows some effort himself =) I will give it some time then fill in the gaps.

Comment: @
N3buchadnezzar:) Putting$\frac{1-x}{1+x}=t$ I can't eliminate the square root of the denominator ...

Comment: See my update in my question...@ N3buchadnezzar

Comment: @S.panja updated.

Answer (score 0):

$\bf{My\; Solution::}$ Given $$\displaystyle \int \frac{1-x}{(1+x)\sqrt{x+x^2+x^3}}dx = -\int\frac{(x^2-1)}{(x+1)^2\sqrt{x+x^2+x^3}}dx$$

We can Write it as $$\displaystyle -\int\frac{\left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)}{\left(x+\frac{1}{x}+2\right)\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{x}+1}}dx$$

Now Let $$\displaystyle \left(x+\frac{1}{x}+1\right)=t^2\;,$$ Then $$\displaystyle \left(1-\frac{1}{x^2}\right)dx = 2tdt$$

So Integral Convert into $$\displaystyle - \int\frac{2t}{(t^2+1)\cdot t}dt = -\int\frac{2}{1+t^2}dt = -2\tan^{-1}(t)+\mathcal{C}$$

So Integral Convert into $$\displaystyle   \int \frac{1-x}{(1+x)\sqrt{x+x^2+x^3}}dx =-2\tan^{-1}\left(\sqrt{x+\frac{1}{x}+1}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$